# Checking if thread is alive

Tags: multithreading, haxe

Is there way to realiable check thread state in Haxe?

I need to check if threads in my pool are still up to expected count, since I suspect they are dying after some time even with try/catch blocks in place.

Only solution that I can see now (after consulting docs) is to refactor thread with timeouts and send ping messages to the main thread, which seems little bit tedious.

Comment: Which Haxe version and which target are you using?

Comment: Hx4 and neko/hl target due to speed of compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a clean solution, but it helps with the tedious part `haxe-concurrent` package does provide Task class that can  help with managing running threads.